# Reconnecting ceiling fan wires

Tags: electrical

I removed a ceiling fan to install a light kit. The light works but now the fan does not.

The initial fan connection was: yellow ceiling wire to blue fan wire / orange ceiling wire to black fan wire / white and gray ceiling wires to white fan wire.

The wall switch has 3 controls. I believe the larger switch controls the outlets.

Of the other 2 smaller switches, one controls the fan and the other the light. Not sure what I did wrong.

Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The colors of the "ceiling" wires  are not familiar, what part of the world are you in ? A photo(s) would help.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include photos of A) the inside of the fan ceiling box and how those wires are connected to the fan/lights, B) the inside of the box with the wall switch(es) that control the fan and the lights and C) pics showing both sides of the switch(es) that control the fan and the lights. Once you've done that, you can take the [tour] and browse through the [help] to learn how to make the most of this site while you're waiting on someone to answer your question.

Comment: @AlaskaMan If OP is in Chicago (or other locale requiring conduit) hots could be _any_ color whatsoever other than white, grey and green. (IIUC)